# Древовидные комментарии - раскрасить через один рядок

Tags: css

Друпал формирует древовидные комментарии  подобным образом. Чет пока не придумал как каждый второй коммент в дереве раскрасить в другой цвет как зебру.

То есть comment 3 и comment 5 должны быть с другим бекграундом.

**Обновлено**: чтобы все понимали добавил структуру комментариев. Первый уровень пускай будет прозрачный, тогда все остальные через один - другим цветом (зебра - прозрачный, цвет, прозрачный, цвет).

```css
.indented {
  margin-left: 65px;
}
div .comment {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="comment">comment 1</div>
 <div class="indented">
  <div class="comment">comment 2</div>
  <div class="indented">
   <div class="comment">comment 3</div>
   <div class="indented">
    <div class="comment">comment 4</div>
    <div class="indented">
     <div class="comment">comment 5</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="comment">comment 1</div>
 <div class="indented">
  <div class="comment">comment 2</div>
  <div class="indented">
   <div class="comment">comment 3</div>
   <div class="indented">
    <div class="comment">comment 4</div>
    <div class="indented">
     <div class="comment">comment 5</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comment">comment 2</div>
  <div class="indented">
   <div class="comment">comment 3</div>
   <div class="indented">
    <div class="comment">comment 4</div>
    <div class="indented">
     <div class="comment">comment 5</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: а `comment 1` почему нет?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев первый уровень пожалуй будет прозрачный,

Comment: @Jean-Claude Какова глубина вложенности комментариев?

Comment: @GlebKemarsky небольшая, может максимальная 4-6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вложенность комментариев невелика, то можно так:

```css
.indented {
  margin-left: 65px;
}
.comment {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.container >.indented >.comment,
.container >.indented >.indented >.indented >.comment,
.container >.indented >.indented >.indented >.indented >.indented >.comment,
.container >.indented >.indented >.indented >.indented >.indented >.indented >.indented >.comment {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="comment">comment 1</div>
 <div class="indented">
  <div class="comment">comment 2</div>
  <div class="indented">
   <div class="comment">comment 3</div>
   <div class="indented">
    <div class="comment">comment 4</div>
    <div class="indented">
     <div class="comment">comment 5</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="comment">comment 1</div>
 <div class="indented">
  <div class="comment">comment 2</div>
  <div class="indented">
   <div class="comment">comment 3</div>
   <div class="indented">
    <div class="comment">comment 4</div>
    <div class="indented">
     <div class="comment">comment 5</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    
  <div class="comment">comment 2</div>
  <div class="indented">
   <div class="comment">comment 3</div>
   <div class="indented">
    <div class="comment">comment 4</div>
    <div class="indented">
     <div class="comment">comment 5</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: да, после вашего комментария-уточнения к моему вопросу сразу подумал о данном решении, на данный момент самое подходящее решение.

Comment: @Jean-Claude При большой глубине вложенности не решился бы предлагать :) Решение именно "на ситуацию".

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .indented {
      margin-left: 65px;
    }
    .comment.__gray {
      background-color: lightgray;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 5px;
    }
    .comment.__black {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="comment __gray">comment 1</div>
<div class="indented">
  <div class="comment __black">comment 2</div>
  <div class="indented">
    <div class="comment __gray">comment 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А если будет 1000 записей?

Comment: Поменять дерево это слишком просто, тут уже по сгенерированному нужно сделать чередование.

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade для тебя есть разница сколько записей? без разницы на самом деле

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, зависит от того как именно расставляются классы, если руками - то разница есть

Comment: @Grundy в фреймворке 1000 записей руками строятся, угу))))

Comment: <div class="indented"> важен для вас?

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade он показывает, что переход на под уровень пошел, видимо да

Comment: Василий разница есть) если ручками прописывать _black или _gray как в ответе, то будет очень гуд по твоему)) Вопрос автору: Изменить структуру можно? Результат будет тем же. Каждый элемент +65 margin-left + цвет меняться будет.

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade `друпал формирует`, я думаю ты уже понял что руками списки не строятся... там просто деф. шаблон есть. Но видимо надо из текущего DOM выбрать чересстрочные элементы, не меняя DOM

Comment: сорри не обратил внимание на друпал. Задачка интересная. Так все решается очень просто. Через nth-child будь это просто div или table. Думаю без помощи js тут не обойтись

Comment: думал можно решить просто css nth-of-type(even/odd), добавление классов изначально не то, что хотелось.

Answer (score 0):

С детьми играть надо (верстка не моя)

```css
}
ul > li {
margin: 5px 0 5px 20px
}
.top-list > li:nth-of-type(odd) > div,
.top-list > li:nth-of-type(odd) li:nth-of-type(even) > div,
.top-list > li:nth-of-type(even) li:nth-of-type(odd) > div,
.top-list > li:nth-of-type(odd) ul ul li:nth-of-type(odd) > div,
.top-list > li:nth-of-type(even) ul ul li:nth-of-type(even) > div{
background: gray;
}
.top-list > li:nth-of-type(even) > div,
.top-list > li:nth-of-type(odd) li:nth-of-type(odd) > div,
.top-list > li:nth-of-type(even) li:nth-of-type(even) > div,
.top-list > li:nth-of-type(odd) ul ul li:nth-of-type(even) > div,
.top-list > li:nth-of-type(even) ul ul li:nth-of-type(odd) > div{
background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
 <ul class="top-list">
<li><div>Пункт 1</div>
    <ul>
        <li><div>Пункт 1.1</div>
            <ul>
                <li><div>Пункт 1.1.1</div></li>
                <li><div>Пункт 1.1.2</div></li>
                <li><div>Пункт 1.1.3</div></li>
                <li><div>Пункт 1.1.4</div></li>                    
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div>Пункт 1.2</div></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><div>Пункт 2</div>
    <ul>
        <li><div>Пункт 2.1</div>
         <ul>
                <li><div>Пункт 2.1.1</div></li>
                <li><div>Пункт 2.1.2</div></li>
                <li><div>Пункт 2.1.3</div></li>
             <li><div>Пункт 2.1.4</div></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div>Пункт 2.2</div></li>
        <li><div>Пункт 2.3</div></li>
        <li><div>Пункт 2.4</div></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><div>Пункт 3</div>
    <ul>
        <li><div>Пункт 3.1</div></li>
        <li><div>Пункт 3.2</div></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```